# How to define 'on-change' sensitivity?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Sensors in android have 4 [trigger modes](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/base_triggers.html) associated to them. one of them is `'on-change'` trigger.
'on-change' mean `events are reported only if the sensor's value has changed`.

I didn't found way how to define the sensitivity(\threshold) of this trigger.
For example, I want light sensor to fire event only if the delta is 2% or 5%.

btw, I found windows support this, see [SENSOR_PROPERTY_CHANGE_SENSITIVITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) propertykey in MSDN.

**EDIT:**

After long investigation I think Android not supported this (change sensitivity manually). **But** I know sensors data is not stable, so Android yet, must define "standard deviation" to fire an event on it..,